# use MapLocationFinder offline?

Tags: windows-10, bing, uwp-maps

i'm having diffcult time in understanding if you can use this tool offline.
As far as i know, you can download maps in windows 10 to use them offline, but on the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.maplocationfinder?view=winrt-20348) the only requirements are to authenticate your app first using a bing key. So my question is: if my final user is not able to use internet, can he still use MapLocatorFinder if he owns a valid Bing Key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the API's in the Windows.Services.Maps namespace, including the the MapLocationFinder will operate offline, assuming you have downloaded data for offline use. The user can download offline maps data through the Windows settings panel, or this can be done via an API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.maps.offlinemaps?view=winrt-20348

Comment: How does Microsoft validate the Bing Key? Cause in the docs it is stated that you must authenticate the uwp app using a valid Bing Key